# Что означает символ ';' в файлах описания запуска сервисов?

Tags: linux

Листинг **/etc/systemd/system/syslog.service**

> ```
> [Unit]
>
> Description=System Logging Service
>
> ;Requires=syslog.socket
>
> [Service]
>
> Type=notify
>
> EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
>
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n $SYSLOGD_OPTIONS
>
> StandardOutput=null
>
> [Install]
>
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
>
> ;Alias=syslog.service
> ```

Comment: 1. приведите, пожалуйста, пример непонятного вам файла. 2. что такое карвисы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что комментарий. Но гарантировать не могу.